# How to use numbers in another vector to specify the name of a matrix in R?

Tags: r

For example, if I create three empty matrices

```
a1<-matrix(NA, 10, 2)
a2<-matrix(NA, 10, 2)
a3<-matrix(NA, 10, 2)
```

and I have another vector

```
b=c(1,2,3,2,3,3)
```

and I want to use the numbers in the vector to refer to one matrix, so a"b[1]" is a1,  a"b[4]" is a2, when I use the matrix, I also want to specify the exact position in the matrix (e.g., a1[1,2]), so the main idea is to use this expression: a"b[1]"[1,2], but what is the correct way to specify this in R? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you meant `a2 <- ...` in the second line.

Comment: Do you mean something like `list(a1,a2,a3)[[ b[1] ]][ 1, 2 ]`  ? It probably makes more sense to collect `a1/2/3/n` into a single `list` object rather than have them floating in your workspace.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes a2 in the second line. What I mean is instead of using a1, a2, a3 directly to represent the matrices, how can I use the values in the vector to represent the matrices and also be able to specify different positions in the matrices, for example, b[5] is 3, how can I use b[5] to represent a3, I know a"b[5]" does not work, also if I want to refer to the first row and first column of a3, which is a3[1, 1], how to use b[5] to do that？a"b[5]"[1,1] does not work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect them in a single `list` object for easy access:

```
amats <- list(a1,a2,a3)
```

Then you can access each matrix by position in the `list`:

```
amats[[1]]
```

Or by using a subset of your `b` variable to select a single matrix

```
amats[[ b[1] ]]
```

Or even multiple matrices at once, possibly multiple times:

```
amats[ b ]
```

You can also chain selections to access a particular cell in a particular matrix, as you request, like:

```
amats[[ b[1] ]][ 1, 2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of something like this:

```r
library(purrr)

a1<-matrix(10, 10, 2)
a2<-matrix(20, 10, 2)
a3<-matrix(30, 10, 2) 

b <- c(1,2,3,2,3,3) %>% 
  map(~ get(paste0('a', .x)))

b[1]
#> [[1]]
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,]   10   10
#>  [2,]   10   10
#>  [3,]   10   10
#>  [4,]   10   10
#>  [5,]   10   10
#>  [6,]   10   10
#>  [7,]   10   10
#>  [8,]   10   10
#>  [9,]   10   10
#> [10,]   10   10

b[4]
#> [[1]]
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,]   20   20
#>  [2,]   20   20
#>  [3,]   20   20
#>  [4,]   20   20
#>  [5,]   20   20
#>  [6,]   20   20
#>  [7,]   20   20
#>  [8,]   20   20
#>  [9,]   20   20
#> [10,]   20   20

b[5]
#> [[1]]
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,]   30   30
#>  [2,]   30   30
#>  [3,]   30   30
#>  [4,]   30   30
#>  [5,]   30   30
#>  [6,]   30   30
#>  [7,]   30   30
#>  [8,]   30   30
#>  [9,]   30   30
#> [10,]   30   30
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>